# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: web3js, infura

I am trying to send ether from one address to another. After executing the code I am receiving an error: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/'))


const addressFrom = 'addr1'
const privateKey = Buffer.from('key', 'hex')
const addressTo = 'addr2'


const txData = {
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(10e9), 
  to: addressTo,
  from: addressFrom,
  value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.0002', 'ether')) 
}


function sendRawTransaction(txData){
  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(txCount => {
    const newNonce = web3.utils.toHex(txCount)
    const transaction = new Tx({ ...txData, nonce: newNonce }, { chain: 'mainnet' }) 
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx)
  })
}

sendRawTransaction(txData).then(result =>
  result
    .on('transactionHash', txHash => {
      console.log('transactionHash:', txHash)
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
      console.log('receipt:', receipt)
    })
    .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
      if (confirmationNumber >= 1) {
        console.log('confirmations:', confirmationNumber, receipt)
      }
    })
    .on('error:', error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
)
```

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: The function sendRawTransaction doesn't have a return statement so it will act like it returned `undefined`. Try adding `return` before `web3.eth.GetTransactionCount(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(txCount => {
    const newNonce = web3.utils.toHex(txCount)
    const transaction = new Tx({ ...txData, nonce: newNonce }, { chain: 'mainnet' }) 
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx)    
    .on('transactionHash', txHash => {
        console.log('transactionHash:', txHash)
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
        console.log('receipt:', receipt)
    })
    .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
        if (confirmationNumber >= 1)
            console.log('confirmations:', confirmationNumber, receipt)
    })
    .on('error:', error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
})
```